Internal Server Error on second Experience Page on the same Domain, having two Custom URLs
I have two separate Experience Pages, available for unauthenticated Guest User. Each page has different Profile, different allowed IP ranges and Permission Set Groups on assigned Guest User.
I need to expose both of them on one Domain but on two different paths. That Domain is already configured on Prod Sandbox.
I tried to setup Custom URL like below - first Experience Page on uat-my-domain.com/guestFoo, second Experience Page on uat-my-domain.com/guestBar

Both CustomURLs were created without error. The first one created works fine, I can successfully open uat-my-domain.com/guestFoo and run the Experience Page content, but upon second address, uat-my-domain.com/guestBar, I get an An internal server error has occurred and page is not accessible.
Error content:

An internal server error has occurred
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.
Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
Error ID: 453521307-83817 (637474174)

Am I doing something wrong here? I'd never think that having simple redirect on separate paths is not possible. I cannot put Experience Page 2 as the subpage of first one, because the IP Ranges and Permissions must be different for these two pages. Are there any work-arrounds?

This reads like XY Problem. Please edit your question and describe what you're trying to accomplish.
